# WooCommerce - How to reset password by custom user meta programmatically

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, filter, hook

The user have metadata called "pin", I need hook of "Reset password" form submit:

I found where validate is checked, I need hook to add my pin validate here:
https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/shortcodes/class-wc-shortcode-my-account.php#L293

WooCommerce endpoint: **example.com/`my-account/lost-password`**

[image]

I need check if the user filled in the field with a **PIN**, and I need intercept default reset password function and check if are a valid PIN, and return a valid data to WooCommerce continue process to reset password.

I do this to login with `add_filter( 'authenticate', 'validateLoginByPin');` but I don't know what I need to filter to reset password. The logic to check are done, but I need correct hook:

```
function resetPasswordByPin($submitedUser) {

    if(isset($submitedUser) && is_numeric($submitedUser)) {
        $pin = $submitedUser;

        $existUser = get_users(
            array(
                'meta_key' => 'pin',
                'meta_value' => $pin,
            )
        );

        if(!empty($existUser) && isset($existUser[0]->data->user_email)) {
            return $existUser[0]->data->user_email; // return e-mail or some valid data to woocommerce continue process...
        }

    }
    return $submitedUser;

}
add_filter('i_dont_know_function_name', 'resetPasswordByPin');
```

How can I do this without edit core files?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [`password_reset`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/password_reset/) hook.

Comment: Is the first hook that I try. The `password_reset` is not called when I submit form, this hooks is called when user receive the e-mail and submit new password. I need hook that is called before this process.

Comment: Then `lostpassword_form` or `validate_password_reset` should be helpful. these are the closest two hooks to submitting the form. You can check the source code here: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.3/src/wp-login.php#L839 and login hooks here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/files/wp-login.php/

Comment: Nope, is not WordPress default recover password, is WooCommerce recover password, I updated question.

Comment: Well just 3 lines below (#296) there is `lostpassword_post` action. So you can do whatever you want here. Like adding the html output of a form in a function in `functions.php`. But this will be a different form, without changing the original one it doesn't look like possible.